# How to check if html if any html element contains text from some Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some object with label and value. Those elements holds some data.
For now i want to loop on html elements and check, what element match this elements. Object is called ui.

[image]

Right now i want to select all elements that contains text from any of object elements.
Those elements have class .img.
Below simple javascript:

```
$("#project").autocomplete({
    source: Items,
    appendTo: ".autocomplete",
    minLength: 2,
    response: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.content.length == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        var content = ui.content[0].label;

        $.each($('.img'), function () {
            if ($(this).is(':contains(' + content + ')')) {
                return;
            } else {
                $(this).fadeOut(100);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This code acts as autocomplete, and i want to hide all emelents that don't match data from ui object.
This code works for me almost fine, but there is one thing that break things:

```
var content = ui.content[0].label;
```

This selects only first item from object, and i'm looking for a way, how to check all items from obejct to check if text contains data, not only from first obejct element [0].

Thanks for advice.

Comment: `:contains` is only for text....show sample of the relevant html as per [mcve]. not really clear if you are looking for text or attributes like `src`

Comment: Ah sorry, i want not clear - .img class is actually an <a> tag. i will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a loop in your $each callback :

```
$.each($('.img'), function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < ui.content.length; i++) {
        var content = ui.content[i].label;
        ...
    }
});
```

EDIT: Change let to var

Comment: Interesting code - but looks like "let" is not valid element here ?

Comment: Keep in mind though that `let` is only available since ES6. I would guess he isn't using that which leads to him needing `var`

Answer (score 0):

I create a jsfiddle for you, If I understand the problem

```
var matchLabelString=_.reduce(ui,function(accumulateString,current){

  if(accumulateString == ""){
    return current.label;
  }
  return accumulateString + "|"+current.label;
},"")

var regex = new RegExp("^"+matchLabelString); 
$.each($('.img'), function () {

     if (regex.test($(this).text())) {
        return;
     } else {
        $(this).fadeOut(100);
     }
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3o1oy5y2/

EDIT: I see your code, and I think that my code work anyway. Try it, as you can see I have used underscore library to create a string seperatad by | from array

Comment: Thanks, but actually my code is a part of autocomplete. So im looking for a way to match all html elements that contains "20" in this case. But my cide is not perfect as i am able to check string only at first obejct element [0] but i want to check all object elements.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand. In the code that  I have posted above, I have created a regexp with the concatenation of all label property of the array, and than check if dom elements match the regexpr